# How did Jamie know about the killings at Dutton Ranch?

Tags: yellowstone

In season 4 episode 1 of Yellowstone, members of a militia attack Dutton ranch and are killed. When Rip shows up he tells Lloyd to get rid of the bodies. In episode 4, Jamie Dutton as the attorney general tells his brother Kayce that he stopped investigations into those 'murders'.

Why does Jamie know anything about the killings of the militia members at Dutton ranch?